# Splitting Observable into windows

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs

I am looking for Observable.Window like operator with opening window selector

As example we can take a sequence of natural numbers. 
I am wondering how to split this sequence into windows so every new window starts if number is greater than 4 or window size has reached 3

Input sequence is `IObservable<int>`
Output sequence is `IObservable<IObservable<int>>`

Sequence 1 2 5 3 1 1 2 3 1 5 0
will produce windows 1 2; 5 3 1; 1 2 3; 1; 5 0

Comment: Should `1, 2, 3, 5` produce the windows `1 2 3; 5` or `1 2 3; ; 5`? (Notice the empty window)

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear ';' - was a separator between desired sequences

Comment: I understand that, but run both answers with the input sequence 1,2,3,5 and they produce different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using C# this works:

```
var observable =
    source
        .Concat(Observable.Return(-1))
        .Publish(sp =>
            sp.Zip(sp.Skip(1), (x0, x1) => new { x0, x1 })
                .Publish(zsp =>
                    zsp
                        .Window(zsp.Where(x => x.x1 >= 4))
                        .Select(xs => xs.Select(x => x.x0).Window(3))
                        .Merge()));
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

Comment: what is the tool you use for visualizing `Observable` results ?

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment on the question I am unsure whether the sequence `1, 2, 3, 5` should produce the windows `1 2 3 | 5` or `1 2 3 | | 5` (see the empty window which is what Enigmativity's answer produces). My answer does not produce the empty window:

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> Window<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int maximumWindowSize)
{
    return Observable.Create<IObservable<T>>(obs =>
    {
        var currentWindow = new Subject<T>();
        obs.OnNext(currentWindow);

        var count = 0;

        return source.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            if (count == maximumWindowSize || predicate(x))
            {
                count = 0;
                currentWindow.OnCompleted();
                currentWindow = new Subject<T>();
                obs.OnNext(currentWindow);
            }
            currentWindow.OnNext(x);
            count++;
        }, obs.OnError, () =>
        {
            obs.OnCompleted();
            currentWindow.OnCompleted();
        });
    });
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
var windows = source.Window(x => x > 4, 3);
```

Comment: I tested mine and didn't get the empty result in the middle. Can you post the code you used to test my code?